# Storybook with React, TypeScript and SASS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, storybook

This is my webpack.config.js in .storybook folder

```
const path = require('path');
const TSDocgenPlugin = require('react-docgen-typescript-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = (baseConfig, env, defaultConfig) => {
  defaultConfig.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    loader: require.resolve('awesome-typescript-loader')
  });
  defaultConfig.plugins.push(new TSDocgenPlugin());
  defaultConfig.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx');
  return defaultConfig;
};
```

This is my `tsconfig.json` config file

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "build/lib",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es5", "es6", "es7", "es2017", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "types": ["node"]
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*", "types/**/*"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "scripts"]
}
```

when i try to import any `scss` file in my any react component i got module not found error.

```
import style from './Button.scss'
```

Please guide me one how to configure `webpack.config.js` to support **scss** `import` in my **tsx** files

Answer (score 2):

Never did with TypeScript, but I guess you'd have to push something like this to your rules:

```
  {
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }, { loader: 'sass-loader' }],
  },
```

So your `webpack.config.js` would look like:

```
const path = require('path');
const TSDocgenPlugin = require('react-docgen-typescript-webpack-plugin');
module.exports = (baseConfig, env, defaultConfig) => {
  defaultConfig.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.(ts|tsx)$/,
    loader: require.resolve('awesome-typescript-loader')
  });
  defaultConfig.module.rules.push({
    test: /\.scss$/,
    use: [{ loader: 'style-loader' }, { loader: 'css-loader' }, { loader: 'sass-loader' }],
  });
  defaultConfig.plugins.push(new TSDocgenPlugin());
  defaultConfig.resolve.extensions.push('.ts', '.tsx');
  return defaultConfig;
};
```

Don't forget to add the loaders to your `package.json`